# Conditions for loop unrolling to be beneficial and the point at which margins of return decrease?

Tags: c++, c, performance, optimization, compiler-construction

Could someone please explain firstly at what point does unrolling a loop (in C/C++) become a useful optimization to do?

Secondly, linked to the first question, at what point should unrolling not be performed any further? Should the unrolling always be performed splitting operations into batches a power of 2? Or does it relate to how many calculations can be performed by your CPU? A ratio which is a multiplier of your cache line size? etc

For example if I had a for-loop from 0 to 99 which would be better/how do I determine which (besides just trial and error)- is there a scientific method:

- 0 to 49 and two "operations" per loop
- 0 to 24 and four "operations" per loop
- 0 to 19 and five "operations"  per loop
- 0 to 9 and ten "operations" per loop

Comment: Is it a problem? If yes, profile, change, and repeat until satisfied. Otherwise leave it.

Comment: Often the compiler can do this for you. It is a micro optimisation, and whether it is useful will depend on the exact situation. Therefore, benchmark.

Comment: (If you can combine loop unrolling with architecture-specific vectorization, it's a different story. That's usually a big boost to performance, and is used by many high-performance libraries. But again it can only be verified by benchmarking)

Comment: Basically, you're just wasting resources if you continue to unroll past the point where the loop overhead (time spent in stepping, condition check, and branch instructions) is small relative to the actual work done in the loop body in one (unrolled) iteration. There's no reason to prefer powers of two or particular divisions, but if the loop has a fixed number of iterations, it may be preferable to make sure the number of unrolled steps divides the number of iterations evenly so you don't need special fixup code for the tail.

Comment: @RalphJohnson if it wasn't a problem I wouldn't be asking.

Comment: Just to echo what @R.. said, I've seen people write `for(...){f(...);}` and ask about unrolling. Unrolling only makes sense if the body of the loop spends *very few* cycles. Anything as costly as a function call almost certainly makes loop unrolling not worthwhile.

Comment: Yeah. Basically the only operations where loop unrolling make sense are the standard string functions (`strlen`, `strchr`, `memcpy`, etc.) and the inner loops of signal processing (audio/video/etc.), cryptography, and so on.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey: But if the loop body is that simple, the compiler (at sufficient optimization level) should be unrolling for you.

Comment: @jxh: That's what's heard in classrooms or echoed across blogs. Maybe it will, and maybe it won't. You have to check the assembly code to find out. There's a big difference between "should" and "does".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't let a question about loop unrolling go unanswered for this long without a mention of [Duff's Device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device). This implementation is a little different from the classic version, but it still works.

Suppose you are applying a mask to a block of memory:

```
while (n-- > 0) {
    *ptr++ &= mask;
}
```

Then, this can be unrolled like this:

```
switch (n % 4) do {
case 0: *ptr++ &= mask;
case 3: *ptr++ &= mask;
case 2: *ptr++ &= mask;
case 1: *ptr++ &= mask;
} while ((n -= 4) > 0);
```

Loop unrolling is useful if the cost of the iteration jump is a significant percentage of the cost of the work done within the loop iteration. A good optimizing compiler can figure that out for you at sufficient optimization levels. You only have to unroll things yourself if your compiler fails to do it.

As mentioned in comments, there is no need to unroll once the computing cost of the jump is no longer significant compared to the compute of the unrolled loop body. Taken to extremes, loop unrolling could lead to instruction cache thrash, hurting performance (similar to over aggressive use of function inlining).